# Accessing global function from [innerHTML] content

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inner-html-rahu1y) I have an Angular component that displays content with `[innerHTML]`. The HTML has an anchor that if clicked it should jump to another line on the page (the line should be shown at the top of the page).

The problem is that I cannot access the javascript function (I named it `goto`) from the inner HTML, even though the function seems to be global.

The error I get is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: goto is not defined`

How to make this work?

```
function goto(id){
   var element = document.getElementById(id);
   element.scrollIntoView(true); 
}

@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class Safe {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}
  transform(html) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<div [innerHTML]="content | safeHtml"></div>'
})
export class AppComponent  {

    content = `      
      <a href=javascript:goto('target')>
           Jump to 'Target' 
      </a>
      <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
      <p id="target">This is 'Target'</p>
    `; 
}
```

Comment: It's not a global function. `window.goto = () => {}` is global

Comment: Why create a global function? You're better off creating a service, decorating it with @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }), and injecting it into your component constructor

Comment: @pixelbits Because the result of innerHTML is not compiled, so I cannot access a service function.

Comment: @Piterden it worked with `(<any>window)`, otherwise TypeScript throws an error saying that `goto` doesn't exist in the Window object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use an inline Javascript. Made few changes to your code to demo this [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inner-html-u6yywt?file=app/app.component.ts).

The `AppComponent` class is as below:

```
export class AppComponent  {

    content = `      
      <a href="#" onClick="(
      function() {
        var element = document.getElementById('target');
        element.scrollIntoView(true); 
      }
    )()">
      Jump to 'Target'
    </a>

    <div id="mydiv" style="height: 250px; width:250px; overflow: auto; background: yellow;">
      <div id="target" style="margin: 500px; height: 500px; width:250px; background-color:green;">
        This is 'Target'
      </div>
    </div>   
    `; 
}
```

**The UI before clicking:**

[image]

**The UI after clicking:**

[image]